# What is difference between nullable datetime property and its field?

Tags: c#, deserialization, nullable

I have a desktop app which uses Serialization and saves data before closing and load same data from file using this code:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var array = (MyClass[])formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

MyClass has a datime property and its field. I need to make it nullable but i got *Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value* InnerException when i made them both nullable like that.

```
    public DateTime? MyDate
    {
        get
        {
            return myDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (myDate != value)
            {
                myDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, I updated my code as follows

```
    public DateTime? MyDate
    {
        get
        {
            return myDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && myDate != value)
            {
                myDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Error occured in deserialization process as before. Then i had to make field non nullable and change property like as follows

```
            public DateTime? MyDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (myDate == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return myDate;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (myDate != value)
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    myDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    myDate = (DateTime)value;
                }

                onPropertyChanged("MyDate");
            }
        }
    }
```

That workaround worked as i expected but i cant understant why second code does not work for DateTime while same code works for nullable decimal properties. what is difference beetween field and propery when they have value of null?

Comment: is your myDate field also nullable?

Comment: I made it nullable in fırst and second tıme but last i had to made it non nullable.

Comment: I did a test locally with nullable property and field and it works as expected. There is probably something else provoking your exception. How your code differs from: https://gist.github.com/avitsidis/9d172a59da326d1d78015687a2be1e06 ?

Comment: BinaryFormatter never serializes properties, only fields.  So the change you made is breaking, be sure to delete all of the old serialized data.

Comment: @asidis i tried the code and it worked but i read from a file there might be differences.
@ hans i also deleted old files and started again. when i create file with nullable datetime field it cant read it.

Comment: @onurdemir can you provide us more inputs so that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Thank so much for your helpfulness. I have to go vacation in an hour.I will try to reproduce it separately from the solution and share here. if i cant i will provide more details next monday.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myDate != value)
{
     myDate = value;
}
```

Might be your problem, not really sure, but performance wise it's not smart to do this anyway because setting the value requires less processing power than to compare it.

So why not make this:

```
public DateTime? MyDate { get;set; }
```

Let me know if that fixes your problem!

Comment: the if block is probably there to avoid notifying property changed (onPropertyChanged("MaturityDate"); in the last sample of code)

Comment: Ye but I wonder if he placed it as a debug code or an attempt of understanding why things are going wrong. Or if it's there for different purposes.

Comment: @onurdemir if you actually use this code, I might suggest that you use a different class that models your serialization object to the file. And a wrapper class (for example) that adds functionality like notifying when a property has changed. Just to make it less complicated when you are focusing on the serialization aspect of your object. You don't have to debug code that has nothing to do with the serialization purpose of the object.

Comment: I updated the code                 onPropertyChanged("MyDate");
i did not wrote it for debug purposes. i am not sure it will work same as when i use autoproperty

Comment: `but performance wise it's not smart to do this anyway because setting the value requires less processing power than to compare it` that's irrelevant. The comparison is due to the typical WPF/MVVM/INotifyPropertyChange pattern. It's not about performance. Besides, if you are calling your properties in a way such that this becomes relevant I think you'll have other performance issues to handle ;-)